# App processing fails with message "This build is invalid."

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

Coinciding with the date for upcoming submission requirements our apps are now not considered valid. We believe that we have meet all the requirements.

Apple says:

> Upcoming Submission Requirements
>
> As a reminder, starting March 27, 2019 all new apps and app updates for iPhone or iPad, including universal apps, will need to be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK and support iPhone XS Max or the 12.9-inch iPad Pro (3rd generation). Screenshots for these devices will also be required. All new apps and app updates for Apple Watch will need to be built with the watchOS 5.1 SDK and support Apple Watch Series 4.

We are actually using Swift 4 at the moment but as far as I can tell everything else is OK. I updated another app that was only using Objective C (which is uploading and processing fine) to use some Swift 4 and it continued to upload and process ok.

We did get an email from Apple about this but it did not contain any useful information:

> App Store Connect
>
> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "[App Name]". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I also used the Validate option in Xcode and the binary is valid.

I have tried using Application loader and Xcode 10.2 to upload.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Check for all the keys and descriptions in plist for all the permissions you are using in your app. Like Locations, gallery etc. Also make sure you are using screenshots from actual devices not from simulators.

Comment: I forgot to say that our CD platform has been uploading to AppStoreConnect without issue for months so I don't think any of those things will be an issue now.

Comment: We have faced the same issue recently. Our app was also getting uploaded just fine and yesterday we got a rejection mail saying we have not added required keys and description in plist. In our case Location key was missing. We have added it and it got uploaded successfully.

Comment: Right so our email has not got any details in it (see above). Seems really weird.

Comment: We faced the same issue today. There is empty lines instead of error in the email.

Answer (score 1):

OK it's working now, seems Apple must have silently fixed something.

Comment: Although we still get an email saying there is an issue however the place where the issues should go is empty.